# Реализация мгновенного поиска c RxJava

Tags: android, rxjava, rxandroid

Пытаюсь делать в своем приложении мгновенный поиск пользователей из удаленной БД с RxJava. Следуя по одной статьи получилось сделать так: Сначала мне приходится получить всех пользователей,а  потом искать их из всех полученных пользователей. Мне надо, чтобы запрос поиска отправлялся прямо на сервер, и чтобы мне сервер давал результат запроса.
Когда я передаю текст поиска так `publishSubject.onNext("");` ,  то запрос срабатывает, сервер дает мне результат. Но чтобы при каждом событии в EditText запрос отправлялся на сервер, сервер давал результат - такое у меня не получается.

При каждом событии в `TextChangeEvent` запрос на поиск не отправляется.

Скажите пожалуйста, должен ли сервер (api который мне дали) поддерживать получения мгновенного результата удаленного поиска? Или у меня в коде в каком-то месте ошибка. Почему не отправляется запрос на поиск?

```
disposable.add(publishSubject.debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .switchMapSingle((Function<String, Single<List<UsersCoordinate>>>) s -> apiClient.getUserService().getUsersSearch("", s)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()))
                .subscribeWith(observer));

        disposable.add(RxTextView.textChangeEvents(binding.etSearch)
                .skipInitialValue()
                .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(searchUsersTextWatcher()));

        disposable.add(observer);
        publishSubject.onNext("");
```

```
    private DisposableObserver<TextViewTextChangeEvent> searchUsersTextWatcher() {
        return new DisposableObserver<TextViewTextChangeEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(TextViewTextChangeEvent textViewTextChangeEvent) {
                publishSubject.onNext(textViewTextChangeEvent.text().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы, кажется, как-то переусложнили код. Должно что-то такое заработать так, как вы описываете:

```
RxTextView.textChangeEvents(searchbar.getEditText())
            .debounce(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .map { it.text().toString() }
            .flatMap { apiClient.getUserService().getUsersSearch("", it) }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe { ... }
```